# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<NA>'

Tags: python, pandas

Have a pandas dataframe, containing a column "counts" of Int64 type which is the nullable integer type.

```
country  date         counts
 US      2020-04-05    <NA>
 US      2020-04-06    <NA>
 US      2020-04-07    <NA>
 US      2020-04-05    0
```

There is part of  downstream code  to process this df, to coerce it to int, `int(counts)` which cause this trouble.
In this case, the `<NA>` is really missing data, I could not fill 0.

Any way to avoid this?
tried: `df["counts"] = df["counts"].astype("Int64")` but it's not working.

Comment: Please remember to use the [tag:pandas] tag on Pandas questions.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

```
df["counts"] = pd.to_numeric(df["counts"],errors='coerce')
```

Or

```
df["counts"]=df["counts"].astype(object)
```

Comment: but this counts is integer.

Comment: @newleaf as object ?